# Spring Security exclude particular URL by using custom annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Below piece of code is working to exclude authentication for particular end point

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String[] excludeEndPoint = { "/getEmployees" };
    private HttpSecurity unifiedConfiguration(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, excludeEndPoint).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

But I want to remove this logic from SpringSecurityConfig class and add some custom annotation(i.e UnauthenticateURL) in method level.

```
Spring Boot API Example :
@GetMapping(path = "/getEmployees")
@UnauthenticateURL
public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() throws Exception {
    ........
    ........
    Buisiness logic
    ........
}

Custom Annotation :

@Target({ METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface UnauthenticateURL {

}
```

Is it possible to implement this logic by using Spring Security with Spring Boot application?

Comment: There is already a annotation of Spring and one of Java. Why do you need another one?

Comment: There's an option to exclude the path via `HttpSecurity`, like it's already done. Or it's even easier to specify the private resources rather than public ones via `@PreAuthorize` annotation or it's custom made wrapper

Comment: @WildDev Yes we can exclude the path via HttpSecurity. Lets consider I have use case to exclude more than 100 API's. So in that case we have to add all 100 API URL's into "antMatchers" manually. To avoid that we are planning to write some custom annotation and use it in method level.

By using PreAuthorize annotation we can not authenticate method level URL's and PreAuthorize annotation will use authorization purpose (example : PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") )

Comment: @user10251274 You could still use `PreAuthorize` annotation. No need for an own annotation.

Comment: I've achieved by using Reflection Library . Here is the piece of code

public Set<String> getAllUnAuthenticatedEndPointUsingReflection(){
 Set<String> endPointSet = new HashSet<>();
 Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.test", new MethodAnnotationsScanner());
 final Set<Method> methods = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(UnauthenticatedEndpoint.class);
 for (final Method method : methods)
 {
  UnauthenticatedEndpoint produce = method.getAnnotation(UnauthenticatedEndpoint.class);
  if (produce != null)
   endPointSet.add(produce.endPoint());
 }
 return endPointSet;
}